# JQuery - load function

Tags: jquery, partial-views

I'm trying to load different content for my website depending on which menu item a user currently has clicked. The initial call to the load(); function works fine. But when clicking a menu item no request is send to the server. No errors appear in console either.

```
$(function () {
    load("Lobby/News");//Works fine

    $("#homeMenuItem").click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        load("Lobby/News");//Doesn't send a new request to server
    });

    $("#otherMenuItem").click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        load("Lobby/Other");//Doesn't send a new request to server
    });
});


function load(location) {
    var $dummy = $("#dummy");

    //Load home by default
    $dummy.load(location, function (response, status, xhr) {
        var $container = $("#lobbyContent");
        if (status != "success") {
            $container.html('an error has occured');
        }
        else {
            $container.html($dummy.html());
        }
        $dummy.remove();
    });
}

<div>
    <section id="lobbyContent" class="row">
        @RenderBody()
        <div id="dummy"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Server is an ASP.NET MVC 5 application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The initial call to the load(); function works fine. But when clicking
>   a menu item no request is send to the server. No errors appear in
>   console either.

`$dummy.remove();` removes `#dummy` element from `DOM` after first call to `load` . When `load` called again there is no `#dummy` element in `DOM` to chain `.load()` method to

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice that. Thanks, works like a charm!

Comment: If anyone would ever land on this question, it was fixed by appending a new div first.    $("#lobbyContent").append("<div id='dummy'></div>");
    var $dummy = $("#dummy");